# field label not supported: NAME

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I use https://github.com/zalando/postgres-operator to deploy PostgreSQL instances and have the following running instances:

```
kubectl get postgresqls.acid.zalan.do 
NAME                   TEAM        VERSION   PODS   VOLUME   CPU-REQUEST   MEMORY-REQUEST   AGE     STATUS
acid-minimal-cluster   acid        12        2      1Gi                                     2d18h   SyncFailed
acid-userdb            acid        12        2      5Gi      100m          100Mi            2d18h   SyncFailed
databaker-userdb       databaker   12        2      2Gi      100m          100Mi            2d18h   SyncFailed
databaker-users-db     databaker   12        2      2Gi      100m          100Mi            2d17h   SyncFailed
```

I try to get the instance as follows:

```
kubectl get postgresql --field-selector NAME=databaker-userdb
Error from server (BadRequest): Unable to find "acid.zalan.do/v1, Resource=postgresqls" that match label selector "", field selector "NAME=databaker-userdb": field label not supported: NAME
```

as you can see, I've got error message.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

The yaml file

```
apiVersion: acid.zalan.do/v1
kind: postgresql
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: user-db
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  creationTimestamp: "2020-06-16T15:58:28Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    team: databaker
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: acid.zalan.do/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:meta.helm.sh/release-name: {}
          f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {}
          f:team: {}
      f:spec:
        .: {}
        f:databases:
          .: {}
          f:users: {}
        f:numberOfInstances: {}
        f:postgresql:
          .: {}
          f:version: {}
        f:resources:
          .: {}
          f:limits:
            .: {}
            f:cpu: {}
            f:memory: {}
          f:requests:
            .: {}
            f:cpu: {}
            f:memory: {}
        f:teamId: {}
        f:users:
          .: {}
          f:databaker: {}
        f:volume:
          .: {}
          f:size: {}
    manager: Go-http-client
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-06-16T15:58:28Z"
  - apiVersion: acid.zalan.do/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        .: {}
        f:PostgresClusterStatus: {}
    manager: postgres-operator
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-06-16T15:58:53Z"
  name: databaker-users-db
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "68486"
  selfLink: /apis/acid.zalan.do/v1/namespaces/default/postgresqls/databaker-users-db
  uid: 8bc3b591-4346-4cca-a1ae-682a1ad16615
spec:
  databases:
    users: databaker
  numberOfInstances: 2
  postgresql:
    version: "12"
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 500Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 100Mi
  teamId: databaker
  users:
    databaker:
    - superuser
    - createdb
  volume:
    size: 2Gi
status:
  PostgresClusterStatus: Running
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular custom resource, but usually you don't need `--field-selector` to pick something out by name; try `kubectl get postgresql databaker-userdb`.

Comment: Yes it works. How to use the selector **STATUS**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/)

> Field selectors let you select Kubernetes resources based on the value of one or more resource fields. Here are some examples of field selector queries:
>
> - metadata.name=my-service
> - metadata.namespace!=default
> - status.phase=Pending

**NAME** is not resource field, You can use like following

```
$ kubectl get postgresql --field-selector metadata.name=databaker-userdb
```

According to documentation

> Supported field selectors vary by Kubernetes resource type. All resource types support the metadata.name and metadata.namespace fields. Using unsupported field selectors produces an error.

To get according to status, you can run

```
$ kubectl get postgresql | grep "SyncFailed"
```

Comment: What about the `STATUS`?

Comment: Can you check by running `kubectl get postgresql --field-selector status.phase=SyncFailed` ?

Comment: it says: `Error from server (BadRequest): Unable to find "acid.zalan.do/v1, Resource=postgresqls" that match label selector "", field selector "status.phase=SyncFailed": field label not supported: status.phase
`

Comment: can you share  `kubectl get postgresql databaker-userdb -o yaml` ?

Comment: I posted the yaml file

Comment: Now can you please run `kubectl get postgresql --field-selector status.PostgresClusterStatus=Running` ?

Comment: `Error from server (BadRequest): Unable to find "acid.zalan.do/v1, Resource=postgresqls" that match label selector "", field selector "status.PostgresClusterStatus=Running": field label not supported: status.PostgresClusterStatus`